# What is the Vertical Line (Encircled in the Picture) in VLC Media Player's Progress Bar?

Tags: vlc

What is the Vertical Line in VLC Media Player's Progress Bar? I've encircled the lines. They keep on appearing and disappearing.

I'm not experiencing any problems. I just wanna know.
Here's the pic:

[image: Vertical Lines in VLC Progress Bar]

Comment: A shot in the dark: [key-frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame#Video_compression).

Comment: I think they are bookmarks, maybe ?

Comment: They can be bookmarks. But when I click on them, around them, or pay attention for changes in the video at that point, I don't see any changes that explains their presence.